# passing a serialized object

Tags: java, serialization, xml-rpc

In xmlrpc objects need to be serialized before they can be transmitted across a network, so this is what I am trying to do.

```
        addAuthorName = txtAddAuthorName.getText();
        int addArticleNumber = Integer.parseInt(txtAddArticleNumber.getText()); 
        newArticle = new Article(addAuthorName, addArticleNumber);
        ObjectOutputStream oos;

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream( 
        new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(newArticle);

        Vector<Object> addArticleArglist = new Vector<Object>();
        addArticleArglist.addElement(oos);
        System.out.println(oos);

        // make the call
        String callit = ("GetSize.addHash");
        articleID = (Integer) client.execute(callit, addArticleArglist);
```

The problem I am getting is that my program will not accept the outputstream that is contained in the vector the error given is

> unsupported Java type: class java.io.ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

You can only serialize objects that implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface. Below statement adds `ObjectOutputStream` to the Vector which doesn't implement that interface.

```
addArticleArglist.addElement(oos);
```

I doesn't see any reason why you have to add that to Vector.

Comment: because of the xmlrpc. it uses the client.execute method which requires you to put the method you want to call on the server and if you want to pass any variables a vector

for more info go here:
http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The serialization happens automatically. You don't need to undertake further action to serialize the object—just use it as a param, and it will automatically be serialized.